# How does walletexplorer.com generate the wallet ID's?

Tags: cryptography

I was wondering how Walletexplorer.com determines what the wallet ID(entifier) of a certain set of adresses ( wallet ) is.

There seems to be no preset like the case with adresses (eg, they all start with 1....X)

more something like

```
0020bb2aef
5dbe0f39c2
43ba59ffbc
71cffa7b7f
```

But rather seems to be "randomly" generated.

Could anyone explain if this is the case, or if it's indirectly generated from something such as the private key, as the case is with normal adresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're internally generated and have no bearing on anything but the internal database, some are sequential and some are random for historical reasons. All information displayed there is inferred, there's no direct relation to transactional information available on the Bitcoin network other than by derivation.